# Difference in calling Dispose when injecting repository directly vs Kernel.Get

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, idisposable

I have a service that has several repositories (bound via ninject like so):

```
Bind<IRepository<User>>().To<Repository<User>>().InRequestScope();
```

Since the service has too many dependencies injected in the constructor, I decided to use a `RepositoryProvider`:

```
public class RepositoryProvider : IRepositoryProvider
{
    private readonly Func<Type, object> factory;

    public RepositoryProvider(Func<Type, object> factory)
    {
        if (factory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("factory");
        }

        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        object repository = factory(type);
        if (repository != null)
        {
            return (IRepository<T>)repository;
        }

        string message = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "No repository found for {0}", type.Name);
        throw new NotImplementedException(message);
    }
}
```

Which gets a repository factory injected via Ninject:

```
Func<Type, object> repositoryFactory = type =>
        {
            Type repositoryType = typeof(IRepository<>).MakeGenericType(type);
            return Kernel.Get(repositoryType);
        };
```

And this provides an instance of a generic repository:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>, IDisposable where T : class
{
    private IEntities context;

    public Repository(IEntities context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        this.context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll() 
    {
        return context.GetDbSet<T>();
    }

    #region IDisposable
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            context.Dispose();
            context = null;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Now, when I inject the repository directly in the service, I see the `Dispose()` method being called immediately after the request (when I set a breakpoint). But when I use the provider I don't see the `Dispose()` called at all.

What could be the cause of this? Do I have everything setup to ensure `Dispose()` being called by ninject?
I see other answers mentioning a "OncePerWebRequest" module, but can't seem to find any documentation on this and don't know whether this is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you changed from ctor injection to factory creation, you changed the "time" the instances are createad. As `InRequestScope()` has worked before, i suggest that the factory-created instances are created at a point where `HttpContext.Current` is invalid/null.

Please note that with changing from ctor injection to factory creation you've openend a new problem: you're now using service-location and your object graph is not (necessarily) created completely from the root in one go. Also [see Mark Seeman's blog post on service locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

To fix "all" problems in one go i suggest slightly adapting the Repository. Instead of having a `IRepository<T>` with methods like `T GetAll()`, why don't you change it to `IRepository` and methods like `T GetAll<T>()`. This way, you need only one repository instance:

```
public class Repository : IRepository, IDisposable
{
    private IEntities context;

    public Repository(IEntities context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        this.context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>() 
        where T : class
    {
        return context.GetDbSet<T>();
    }

    #region IDisposable
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            context.Dispose();
            context = null;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```